# Android GitHub API multiple HttpConnections same time

Tags: android, android-asynctask, github-api

I am working on Android application which uses a **GitHub API**. Now at the current screen which is repository screen I need to get : *commits count, releases count, branch count, contributors count, issues and to check that is this repository starred by the authenticated user*. I implemented this logic with `AsyncTask`. I dont like that I use 6 tasks same time with `ExecuteOnExecutor`. I think that is not good practice but I can not find other way.

1. Could you please give me some tips for that how can I do that logic in other way?
2. Also I want to ask you guys which is the best way to make this GitHub API request? I can not make decision what technology to use - AsyncTask or IntentService or something else.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsyncTask is almost always the wrong choice: complicated error handling, cumbersome API, different implementations on different OS versions, etc.

I would recommend you to take a look at [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) library. It has a really nice and easy API to make REST API calls and even parse the responses with [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) if you like. Also, it takes care of the asynchronousity.

If you want to go further, I encourage you to check out [rx-java](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava). It might be a complete overkill in your case, and the learning curve is pretty steep, but if you decide to go with it, it opens up an endless possibilities of how to elegantly handle situations such as yours.

Comment: Thanks Roberto. I think I will use Retrofit. Its looking very well and also easy for understanding for a couple of hours. Do you know which type of thread implementation uses this library?

Comment: By default it uses CachedThreadPool executor, but you can provide it with whatever Executor you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a `SyncAdapter` and store the data locally. This way you can let the data sync in the background after a certain period of time (let's say daily). The great advantage of this is that you can check recent data offline even if you havent started your app in the last couple of days. You can also run the `SyncAdapter` manually to ensure the latest data.

Comment: Thank you dumazy. I didnt know for this SyncAdapter and sounds very good but I dont have a time to do it in this way.